# Laravel Eloquent query with join, count and group by

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to remake this query:

```
return DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(orders.id), name FROM orders JOIN users ON orders.manager_id = users.id GROUP BY users.id"));
```

I have `Order` model which has links to another tables using `belongsTo()` method, there are several of them:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'manager_id');
}
```

When I use simple queries like `Order::all()` it works fine but I've tried to call this:

```
return Order::groupBy('users.id')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(orders.id), name')
        ->get();
```

Of course, Laravel don't know should I use either user name or manager name as it's two relations with `users` table in `Order`. How should I write the query above properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Order::groupBy('users.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(orders) AS TOTAL_ORDERS'))
        ->addSelect('name')
        ->get();
```

You can count with DB:raw i think it will work for u.